# how to read the img tag inside the description tag of rss

Tags: android, parsing, rss

I am trying to read yahoo weather rss and display them in my android application.

There is an img src="url of the image" tag in side the < description>< /description> tag of the rss.

But I do not know how to read that url. Can anybody plz help me in this regard?

Here is my code:

```
public class RssReader {

private final static String BOLD_OPEN = "<B>";
private final static String BOLD_CLOSE = "</B>";
private final static String BREAK = "<BR>";
private final static String ITALIC_OPEN = "<I>";
private final static String ITALIC_CLOSE = "</I>";
private final static String SMALL_OPEN = "<SMALL>";
private final static String SMALL_CLOSE = "</SMALL>";

public static List<JSONObject> getLatestRssFeed(){
    String feed ="http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=554890&u=c"; 

    RSSHandler rh = new RSSHandler();
    List<Article> articles =  rh.getLatestArticles(feed);
    Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Number of articles " + articles.size());
    return fillData(articles);
}
private static List<JSONObject> fillData(List<Article> articles) {

    List<JSONObject> items = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (Article article : articles) {
        JSONObject current = new JSONObject();
        try {
            buildJsonObject(article, current);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Error creating JSON Object from RSS feed");
        }
        items.add(current);
    }

    return items;
}
private static void buildJsonObject(Article article, JSONObject current) throws            JSONException {
    String title = article.getTitle();
    String description = article.getDescription();
    String date = article.getPubDate();

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(BOLD_OPEN).append(title).append(BOLD_CLOSE);
    sb.append(BREAK);
    sb.append(description);
    sb.append(BREAK);
    sb.append(SMALL_OPEN).append(ITALIC_OPEN).append(date).append(ITALIC_CLOSE).append(SMALL_CLOSE);

    current.put("text", Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));
}
}
```

SO here the img tag is inside the Description tag. How can I read it?? any help??

Here is the RSSHandler:

```
public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

// Feed and Article objects to use for temporary storage
private Article currentArticle = new Article();
private List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<Article>();

// Number of articles added so far
private int articlesAdded = 0;

// Number of articles to download
private static final int ARTICLES_LIMIT = 15;

//Current characters being accumulated
StringBuffer chars = new StringBuffer();


/* 
 * This method is called everytime a start element is found (an opening XML marker)
 * here we always reset the characters StringBuffer as we are only currently interested
 * in the the text values stored at leaf nodes
 * 
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler#startElement(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.xml.sax.Attributes)
 */
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) {
    chars = new StringBuffer();
}



/* 
 * This method is called everytime an end element is found (a closing XML marker)
 * here we check what element is being closed, if it is a relevant leaf node that we are
 * checking, such as Title, then we get the characters we have accumulated in the StringBuffer
 * and set the current Article's title to the value
 * 
 * If this is closing the "Item", it means it is the end of the article, so we add that to the list
 * and then reset our Article object for the next one on the stream
 * 
 * 
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler#endElement(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
 */
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
    {
        Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article title: " + chars.toString());
        currentArticle.setTitle(chars.toString());

    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
    {
        Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article description: " + chars.toString());
        currentArticle.setDescription(chars.toString());
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate"))
    {
        Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article published date: " + chars.toString());
        currentArticle.setPubDate(chars.toString());
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("encoded"))
    {
        Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article content: " + chars.toString());
        currentArticle.setEncodedContent(chars.toString());
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
    {

    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
    {
        try {
            Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article link url: " + chars.toString());
            currentArticle.setUrl(new URL(chars.toString()));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("RSA Error", e.getMessage());
        }

    }




    // Check if looking for article, and if article is complete
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

        articleList.add(currentArticle);

        currentArticle = new Article();

        // Lets check if we've hit our limit on number of articles
        articlesAdded++;
        if (articlesAdded >= ARTICLES_LIMIT)
        {
            throw new SAXException();
        }
    }
}





/* 
 * This method is called when characters are found in between XML markers, however, there is no
 * guarante that this will be called at the end of the node, or that it will be called only once
 * , so we just accumulate these and then deal with them in endElement() to be sure we have all the
 * text
 * 
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler#characters(char[], int, int)
 */
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    chars.append(new String(ch, start, length));
}





/**
 * This is the entry point to the parser and creates the feed to be parsed
 * 
 * @param feedUrl
 * @return
 */
public List<Article> getLatestArticles(String feedUrl) {
    URL url = null;
    try {

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        url = new URL(feedUrl);

        xr.setContentHandler(this);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("RSS Handler IO", e.getMessage() + " >> " + e.toString());
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("RSS Handler SAX", e.toString());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("RSS Handler Parser Config", e.toString());
    }

    return articleList;
}
```

Comment: We need some more details, what is the format? How are you parsing it?

Answer (score 1):

you should use webview to display information from descripion:

```
loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding)
```

Load the given data into the WebView.

- you custom data html

Answer (score 0):

I thin you would be better off using YQL and JSON rather than RSS. Anyways if ur using rss u need to parse the xml. A sax parser is built in Android itself